# Android, Can't bind port 67(dhcp) on my device

Tags: android, permission-denied

1. I have added internet permission in the mainfest.xml.
2. I want to send and receive dhcp messages. Actually, I want to know the domain name of the network which I am connecting. But there aren't any workable methods on Android APIs.(If anyone knows?)

   ```
   03-26 17:50:42.130: W/System.err(6747): java.net.BindException: bind failed: EACCES (Permission denied)
   ```

Answer (score 1):

i know unix operating systems forbid applications that don't run as root to bind on ports equal to or less than 1024.

Comment: Yes, so that's why I ask the question, I hope there is some other ways to get across, or directly get the domain name I want. I use DHCP for an inform request.